# Sort view based on weight of taxonomy vocabulary inside field collection

Tags: sorting, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-field-collection

I got a view to list a content type (Say faculty). Among many fields, I have a field collection (Say position) which got a Designation field (Taxonomy Vocabulary).

Now I need an exposed filter criteria and sort criteria to sort the entire content based on this Designation inside this field collection.

By adding a relationship, I managed to apply the filter using "Designation", But I am unable to sort the content using the **weight** of this "Designation" taxonomy. 
Note: Sort by taxonomy name is working. The problem is sorting with the **weight** of taxonomy.

[image: SCreen shot of View]

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you are asking.  You have a content type, that type has a field collection, the field collection has a term reference.  I see you have chained the relations to get through that, but what are you doing with the aggregation?  Could you add a screenshot of the preview space below the view configuration?

Comment: Maybe check your taxonomy terms having a weight specified because by default it's 0 on creation of terms. & To control the sorting by weight of your taxonomy, you need to enable the exposed option on the **sorting criteria** too.

Comment: Hii, Thank you for your comments. I got this issue resolved, I missed to tick "Require this relationship" in Configure Relationship option.